# R: count unique values from group to group by date

Tags: r

I have dataframe like this

| Game date | Team | Player |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-09-12 | Liverpool | A |
| 2020-09-12 | Liverpool | B |
| 2020-09-12 | Liverpool | C |
| 2020-09-12 | Man Utd | D |
| 2020-09-12 | Man Utd | E |
| 2020-09-12 | Man Utd | F |
| 2020-09-12 | Arsenal | G |
| 2020-09-12 | Arsenal | H |
| 2020-09-12 | Arsenal | I |
| 2020-09-15 | Liverpool | A |
| 2020-09-15 | Liverpool | B |
| 2020-09-15 | Liverpool | C |
| 2020-09-15 | Man Utd | D |
| 2020-09-15 | Man Utd | E |
| 2020-09-15 | Man Utd | Q |
| 2020-09-15 | Arsenal | G |
| 2020-09-15 | Arsenal | O |
| 2020-09-15 | Arsenal | I |
| 2020-09-18 | Liverpool | A |
| 2020-09-18 | Liverpool | B |
| 2020-09-18 | Liverpool | C |
| 2020-09-18 | Man Utd | M |
| 2020-09-18 | Man Utd | H |
| 2020-09-18 | Man Utd | Q |
| 2020-09-18 | Arsenal | G |
| 2020-09-18 | Arsenal | H |
| 2020-09-18 | Arsenal | I |

And I would like to count how many unique values appears in Team comparing to the previous game day (exactly to the last game. If player appears in first game, misses second and appears in third game, he should be could as unique value in third game).

Desired output

| Game date | Team | Unique players |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-09-15 | Liverpool | 0 |
| 2020-09-15 | Man Utd | 1 |
| 2020-09-15 | Arsenal | 1 |
| 2020-09-18 | Liverpool | 0 |
| 2020-09-18 | Man Utd | 2 |
| 2020-09-18 | Arsenal | 1 |

Is there any elegant way to do this?

Comment: When you say *"how many unique values appears in Team comparing to the last game day"* I'm not sure exactly what you mean by *"comparing"*. Do you mean that you only want  count players that **did not** play the previous game day?

Comment: ...and by *"last game day"* do you mean the game day with the maximum date? Or do you mean the immediately previous game day?

Comment: It would help a lot if you could explain in detail one or two rows of the output. For 2020-09-15 Arsenal, why is the desired result `1`? Why is 2020-09-18 Arsenal not part of the results, but 2020-09-18 Liverpool is part of the results?

Comment: Yes, I would like count only players that did not play the previous game day.

Edited some mistakes in the desires output.

In 2020-09-15 Arsenal has one new player (comparing to the previous game day). It is "O".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df |> 
  group_by(Game_date, Team) |>
  summarize(players = list(unique(Player))) |>
  group_by(Team) |>
  arrange(Game_date) |>
  mutate(
    prev = lag(players),
    unique_new_players = mapply(\(x, y) length(setdiff(x, y)), players, prev)
  ) |>
  slice(-1) |>
  ungroup() |>
  select(Game_date, Team, unique_new_players)
# # A tibble: 6 × 3
#   Game_date  Team      unique_new_players
#   <chr>      <chr>                  <int>
# 1 2020-09-15 Arsenal                    1
# 2 2020-09-18 Arsenal                    1
# 3 2020-09-15 Liverpool                  0
# 4 2020-09-18 Liverpool                  0
# 5 2020-09-15 Man_Utd                    1
# 6 2020-09-18 Man_Utd                    2
```